# Sign formatting of integer arrays in numpy

Tags: numpy

For floating point numbers, [numpy.set_printoptions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html) has the parameter `sign` with options

- `'-'` : only print minus signs
- `'+'` : always print plus signs
- `' '` : print space instead of plus sign

However, this function only affects `float` arrays. Is there an analog for `int` arrays?

Comment: "{:>+5.0f}".format(1)  The format minilanguage is listed here … https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language

Comment: @NaN but I would have to apply this to every single array I want to print, which is not what I am looking for. `np.set_printoptions` works globally.

Comment: it was the link that was important for the mini-format language which, as you can see, can be used with custom formatters as in my example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass it as a custom format using `formatter`:

```
np.set_printoptions(formatter={'int': lambda x: "{:>+}".format(x)})
print(5-np.arange(10))
>>[+5 +4 +3 +2 +1 +0 -1 -2 -3 -4]
```